# How to migrate millions of rows of data from SQL Server to any client or cloud?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-web-api, cloud, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have code to upload data from SQL Server to snowflake.
Steps:

1. Load data from SQL server & create CSV file along with data
2. Upload CSV to Snowflake staging tables & then process staging & push data to actual  tables.

This works fine.
Now I want to process millions of records. What is efficient way to do so?
How do I work with batches?
I'm using WEB API 2.0

Thanks

Comment: Please be more specific, that's probably the reason why your question is being downvoted. Please include the context, use case and safe samples of the data you are dealing with, also include versions you are working on, that would help the community to provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. create csv file of database you want to upload
2. upload the csv file to AWS(S3 bucket)
3. upload data from S3 bucket to snowflake
   [more details](https://hevodata.com/blog/microsoft-sql-server-to-snowflake/)

Comment: I know steps and I have already mentioned in my question. I want to know effective way to send millions of records. I know we could do this with batches. I just want to know its implementation.

Comment: @RahulMane the above mentioned method is "effective and optimal up/beyond the trillions of rows" aka it's how everybody else is doing it.